# Duplicate column name 'model_id' django mysql error on migrate

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite, django-models

I am using Django and MySQL on my VPS. Whenever I run `python manage.py migrate` I get the following error. But on my development server I use sqlite, and migrate works fine.

```
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying bloupergroups.0002_auto_20160826_1138...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 200, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 92, in migrate
    self._migrate_all_forwards(plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 121, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 198, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 123, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 62, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/schema.py", line 50, in add_field
    super(DatabaseSchemaEditor, self).add_field(model, field)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 396, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 110, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 112, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 226, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/ashish/Env/bloup/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'blouper_id'")
```

I do not understand what the problem is here.

Comment: Please show your models.

Comment: All models? Or any specific one?

Answer (score 3):

Django is probably trying to apply migrations that have already been applied.

Try running `python manage.py migrate --fake-initial`

From the docs:

> --fake-initial
>   Allows Django to skip an app’s initial migration if all database tables with the names of all models created by all CreateModel operations in that migration already exist. This option is intended for use when first running migrations against a database that preexisted the use of migrations. This option does not, however, check for matching database schema beyond matching table names and so is only safe to use if you are confident that your existing schema matches what is recorded in your initial migration.

Comment: `
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states... DONE
  Applying bloupergroups.0002_auto_20160826_1138... FAKED
  Applying feedback.0001_initial... OK
` This was the output