# OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'new_description'")

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-1.8

I had an existing model Services which had some fields including. I wanted to add another field to it, so I did this:

```
class Services(models.Model):
    description = models.TextField()  # Already existing field
    new_description = models.TextField(default=description)  # Newly added field
```

When I ran migrations (makemigrations followed by migrate), I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'TextField' object has no attribute 'model'
```

I couldn't determine what the error was, so I deleted the newly created migration file, and ran the migrations again. I added the field new_description again and tried running the migrations again and got the following error:

```
OperationalError: (1060, "Duplicate column name 'new_description'")
```

What am I missing and how do I correct this?

Comment: You need to show the full traceback of your first error to see where exactly does the error happen. You second error is because you've already migrated the deleted migration and the column has been added. Delete the migration file doesn't move the column in database level. You need to manually delete the column in your database shell.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165779/duplicate-column-name-model-id-django-mysql-error-on-migrate. Try `python file.py migrate --fake-initial`.

Comment: you can't set the `new_description` default to another field in model definition. you have to override the `save` method to assign a default value to `new_description` field... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380879/django-model-field-default-based-off-another-field-in-same-model